# Linq to Group By

Tags: linq, telerik-open-access

I have a function say

```
GetGroupByData(DateTime p1,DateTime p2) 
{
    var data = dbContex.tableName
                       .Where(someconditions)
                       .GroupBy(x=>SqlScalarFunction(x.DateStart,p1));
}

     CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SqlScalarFunction(@Date DateTime, @DateFirst DateTime) 
     RETURNS Int 
     AS 
       BEGIN 
        RETURN Cast((cast(@Date - @DateFirst as float) / 7.0) as int) + 1
         END
```

I am getting an error:

> Column 'tableName.DateStart' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained  in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.

How can I achieve the desire grouping?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your posts in future. You're more likely to get an answer if your post is readable - use the preview before you post, and fix it until it's how you'd want it to look if you were trying to answer the question.

Comment: can you show some code about `SqlScalarFunction`

Comment: the error says that the `DateStart` column is not exist in `GROUP BY clause`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue as

```
GetGroupByData(DateTime p1,DateTime p2) 
{
 var function = "dbo.SqlScalarFunction({0}, '" + p1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')";
   var data = dbContex.tableName.Where(someconditions)
   .GroupBy(x => function.SQL<Int32>(x.DateStartUTC));
}
```

I found the solution here :http://www.telerik.com/forums/converting-to-datetime-in-where-clause

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach you can use to group the objects by the result of a scalar-valued function would be to create a domain method for it, and to consume it in your code as demonstrated below:

```
using (EntitiesModel dbContext = new EntitiesModel())
{
    var query = from obj in dbContext.MyTableNames
                group obj by EntitiesModel.SqlScalarFunction(someDate, someOtherDate) into objg
                select new
                {
                    MyRange = objg.Key,
                    MyResult = objg
                };
}
```

If you are using a domain model (an .rlinq file) you can follow [the guidelines from this article](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/stored-procedures-and-functions/developer-guide-crud-sp-support-domain-method-db-functions#creating_domain_method_for_a_scalar-valued_function), in order to create the *SqlScalarFunction()* domain method. If you have a fluent model, you need to manually add such a method for the function in your context class - the same article will show you the pattern the method has to follow.

Let me know, if this works for you.